# Limits of composite functions

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{u \to c}f(u)=b$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=c$ then $\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=b$
$$$$ Now as $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=c$ we can make $g(x)$ as close to $c$ as we want by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ and also we can make $f(u)$ as close to $b$ as we want by making $u$ sufficiently close to $c$ so we can make $f(g(x))$ as close to $b$ as we want by making $g(x)$ sufficiently close to $c$ and we can make this by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$. So $\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=b$
$$$$ But in a book I saw a counterexample in which $g(x)$ was taken as constant and it was written that this counterexample is impossible if $x \neq a \implies g(x) \neq c$
$$$$ So I want to know that why does the proof becomes wrong when $g(x)$ is constant and what does the line $x \neq a \implies g(x) \neq c$ mean?

Comment: That statement is not true in general, so you can't prove it. If you impose certain conditions, then it can be true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions

Comment: But where is the proof wrong??

Comment: Here is one problem. What if $g(x)$ *equals* $c$ in a neighborhood of $a$? Then $f(g(x))=f(c)$ in that neighborhood but $\lim_{u\to c}f(u)=b$ doesn't tell you anything about $f(c)$ (in fact it can be anything). So you cannot evaluate the limit of the composite function.

Comment: In your first limit $f(u) \to b$ as $u\to c$ it is ensured that $u\neq c$. Essentially you substitute $u=g(x) $ and thus you must ensure that $g(x) \neq c$ as $x\to a$. Without this condition your rule wont work.

Comment: Your argument for the rule is almost correct. You just need to replace "sufficiently close" with "sufficiently close but not equal". If you read the definition of limit carefully you will find the emphasis on "not equal".